# How to create a Combobox that saves users input from a Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, input, combobox, widget

These codes add the user input in the values of `Combobox` but it only have one selection on the combobox.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x350")


def callback():
    ex = entry.get()
    cb['values'] = ex
    entry.delete(0, END)


entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button = Button(root, text="add", command=callback)
button.pack()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: From what I can remember `cb["values"]` should be a tuple or a list but you are giving it a string. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Create a list say `var` and append `entry.get()` to this list now assign `cb['values'] = var`.

Comment: JacksonPro . I want to input names on the entry widgets and stored it on the combobox values.